# Method return null list

Tags: java, json

I read a json file with this method.

```
 public class StudentListJson {
    
        public static List<Student> getStudentList() throws IOException {
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              List<Student> studentList = null;
              String fileName = "C:/Users/bar1s/IdeaProjects/Week4/src/main/java/student.json"; 
    
              String stringJson=new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    
              studentList=Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(stringJson,new TypeReference<>(){}));
    
              ProcessController.isReaded=true;
              return studentList;
          }
          
    }
```

json file :

```
 [
    {"name":"name1", "surname":"surname1", "age": 18},
    {"name":"name2", "surname":"surname2", "age": 19},
    {"name":"name3", "surname":"surname3", "age": 20},
    {"name":"name4", "surname":"surname4", "age": 21}
  ]
```

With this class I try to get list of json and print it but the studentList is null.

```
public class ReadJson implements Runnable  {


    public static List<Student> studentList;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            System.out.println("Reading thread is sleeping");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            studentList = StudentListJson.getStudentList();
            studentList.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toString()));



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Student class.

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

getStudentList method can read the file and inside that method i can print all list but when I try return that list then I try print that list in ReadJson class that list get null. Why?

This code return null, this is my problem.

```
   studentList = StudentListJson.getStudentList();
```

Comment: Could you explain how this Runnable is launched ? It seems your problem is context-related. If I change ReadJson.run() to a main method, it works fine.

Comment: How did you find `studentList` is null? If you see NPE, please post the stacktrace also.

Comment: You tagged this question, [tag:multithreading]. Why? Your example code all appears to run in a single thread. What other thread interacts with it? How do they interact? I am not familiar with Jackson, but maybe you aren't using the `ObjectMapper` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to include the desired type of list elements to the TypeReference?

```
new TypeReference<Student>() { }
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. I tried this then I have got an error.  The error was " com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type Student .... ". Finally I solve the problem with this code. studentList=mapper.readValue(stringJson,
                        mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Student.class));